# How to use process.env to access API key in React app set up with yarn and vite

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, vite, .env

I'm trying to build an e-commerce app and I have used **yarn create vite** to begin my app build.

I'm trying to store my API key and url in a .env file.

I'm attempting to access the variables in the .env file using this code:

```
   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchData = async () => {
         try {
            const data = await axios.get(
               process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/products",
               {
                  headers: {
                     Authorization: "bearer" + process.env.REACT_APP_API_TOKEN,
                  },
               }
            )
            console.log(data)
         } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
         }
      }
      fetchData()
   }, [])
```

When I open the console in the browser, I am getting the following error:

*ReferenceError: process is not defined*

Any idea on how I can define process to use process.env to access the API variables?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation provided by clxrity. I changed code and variable names to what is shown below and everything worked fine:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
     try {
        const data = await axios.get(
           `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL}/products`,
           {
              headers: {
                 Authorization: `bearer ${
                    import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_TOKEN
                 }`,
              },
           }
        )
        console.log(data)
     } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
     }
  }
  fetchData()
```

}, [])